# Cloning table row fails in php, but succeeds via sql shell

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

### Cloning table row GONE WRONG. You wont *believe* codesnippet 2

Sorry about that.

So, I'm trying to clone a table row in a table containing lots and lots of coloumns. Naturally I dont want to name each and every coloumn.
I have found a solution, and this works **perfectly** in the *mySQL WorkBench interface(sql shell)*. Here I am cloning the row with PK="TEST", and I want the resulting row to have a PK of "TEST1"

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl SELECT * FROM pianos WHERE pianoID = $oldPianoID;
UPDATE temp_tbl SET pianoID = '$newPianoID' WHERE pianoID = '$oldPianoID';
INSERT INTO pianos SELECT * FROM temp_tbl;
DROP TABLE temp_tbl;
```

but when applying this sql-script in php, it fails and gives me the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE temp_tbl SET pianoID = 'TEST1' WHERE pianoID = 'TEST';
                INSERT INTO ' at line 2
```

Again, this works in the shell, but not on the server I am running with PHP5 and MariaDB 10.0.23

I thought maybe there might be an issue with some fields using blob-storage, but I can't get this to make sense, as it works with the shell.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Are you usingthe same user in the shell VS the php code?

Comment: Yes, both instances use the same login credentials to connect with the sql-server

Comment: You're not, by any chance, attempting to execute that `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` query **and** the `UPDATE ... ` query in the same `mysqli::query()` (or equivalent) via PHP are you?

Comment: Yes, I am executing the entire first snippet of code in one query.
mysqli::query("$snippetGoesHere");

Comment: Yeah - that won't work, the PHP MySQL interface only allows you to execute one query at a time unless you use something like `multi_query` : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Ohhh, Trying with mysqli_multi_query() now

Comment: Thank you so much @CD001 ! You saved my day! If you want to submit your answer, I will mark it as accepted

Comment: Oki - glad it worked ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE temp_tbl SET pianoID = 'TEST1' WHERE pianoID = 'TEST';
                INSERT INTO ' at line 2
```

You're attempting to execute 2 queries at once - which you can't do through a standard `mysqli::query()` - you need to use `mysqli::multi_query()` instead.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 0):

Carreful, you use simple quote allways

You need to change your code :

```
'UPDATE temp_tbl SET pianoID = 'TEST1' WHERE pianoID = 'TEST';
```

to :

```
'UPDATE temp_tbl SET pianoID = "TEST1" WHERE pianoID = "TEST"';
```

For insert var in string in PHP, you can use different possibility : Double quote or contactain

In doble quote, PHP interpret the code, no in simple quote.

Si, you can write :

```
$sql = "UPDATE temp_tbl SET pianoID = '$var' WHERE pianoID = '$var2'";
```

or :

```
$sql = 'UPDATE temp_tbl SET pianoID = "'.$var.'" WHERE pianoID = "'.$var2.'"';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

```
$var  = 'test1';
$var2  = 'test';


echo "UPDATE temp_tbl SET pianoID = '$var' WHERE pianoID = '$var2'";
// show : UPDATE temp_tbl SET pianoID = 'test1' WHERE pianoID = 'test'
```

Comment: How do I reference variables from PHP without single ticks?
Backticks (`) didnt work, and quotes (") doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

if newPianoId is are not important you can use this sql:

```
INSERT INTO pianos SELECT CONCAT(pianoID,UNIX_TIMESTAMP()), column1, column2, column3, ... FROM pianos WHERE 1
```

with this sql you will dublicate all your pianos with new IDs. Please note that your pianoID column has enough space of UNIX_TIMESTAMP() output, atleast i want to try to give the idea.

PS: you can use where clause if you dont need the dublicate all data. like

```
WHERE pianoID < 123456 AND create_date <= '2016-03-10'
```

etc.

Comment: By the way you can set the new pianoID on php side like `INSERT INTO pianos SELECT ".$newPianoId.", colomn2, column3, ..`